# Offline Event Listener not working in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, cordova, offline

I'm building a project in Apache Cordova, and I have the **org.apache.cordova.network-information** plugin installed.  I have the following code that runs my application:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener('online', onOnline, false);
    document.addEventListener('offline', onOffline, false);
    alert('device ready!');
}

function onOnline() {
    alert('online');
}

function onOffline() {
    alert('offline');
}
```

Whenever I run the iOS simulator **with the laptop's Wifi turned on**, I only get the "device ready" alert.  Whenever I toggle the laptop Wifi off and on, I never see the offline/online alerts.

However, whenever I run my iOS simulator **with the Wifi turned off**, all of the code works properly.  I will get the alert "device ready" when the app loads, followed by an "offline" alert.  When I turn the Wifi on, I get the alert "online" as expected.  However, if I turn the Wifi back off, the "offline" alert does not fire, and toggling the Wifi on and off will not fire the appropriate alerts.

It appears that once the iOS simulator detects an Internet connection, the online and offline listeners become permanently disabled.  Does anyone have any insight as to why I am seeing this unusual behavior?  And is there a solution to this problem?